# Swift : Disable FrontViewController when Rear is Displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to disable interaction with front view when left or right views are revealed. How to do this ?

All the sources are written in objective-C

for example this one

```
    - (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    if(position == FrontViewPositionLeft) {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}

- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    if(position == FrontViewPositionLeft) {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
}
```

**Update**

This is Front View Controller 
didn't work either

```
class Feed: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {




@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.revealViewController().delegate = self


    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
        {
            if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
            {
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
            }
            else
            {
                self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
            }


        }

        fetchMessages()
    }
}
```

Comment: your coding is fine what the problem u faced...

Comment: this is in objective-c I only know swift

Comment: check my updated answer , I written in both language what the result u need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use any one method , it is fine

**Swift**

```
func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
{
 if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
 {
 self.view.userInteractionEnabled=False
 }
 else
 {
 self.view.userInteractionEnabled=true
 }

}
```

don't forget to add `self.revealViewController().delegate = self` in your view controller else , the delegate not called

**Objective-c**

```
 - (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
if(position == FrontViewPositionLeft) {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
} else {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
}
```

don't forget to add `self.revealViewController.delegate = self;` in your view controller else , the delegate not called

**update/customize**

```
class Feed: UIViewController,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

if self.revealViewController() != nil {
    menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
    menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
    self.revealViewController().delegate = self
 self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

}

  fetchMessages()
}

 func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
    {
        if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
        {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        else
        {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }


    }
```

Comment: if you call this method surely works , but don't forget to add delegate in your view controller else the delegate method not called

Comment: I get this error in the delegate method cannot assign a value of type “feed” to a value of type SWRevealControllerDelegate   feed is the frontVC :: shall I add to the menu VC or the front ? and where to add it

Comment: r u added **SWRevealViewControllerDelegate** in your view controller

Comment: no how to do it ? in SWRevealController VC or The feed VC

Comment: @marrioa -- I am understand your question

Comment: I mean : How to add SWRevealViewControllerDelegate to VC ? and Which VC front or the SWRevealViewController VC

Comment: which VC  are you added in **SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController**, thats is your front VC on that VC add **SWRevealViewControllerDelegate**,

Answer (score 2):

Try it.

```
func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController, didMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {

if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
else {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

we made mistake first condition is true and the second is false

```
    func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
{
    if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }

    func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, didMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition)
    {
        if position == FrontViewPosition.Left     // if it not statisfy try this --> if revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPosition.Left
        {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else
        {
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }

    }
```